# How to debug scala driver mongo codes?

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework

My app has mongo codec registry

```scala
object MongoCodecs {
  def Codecs: CodecRegistry = fromRegistries(
    fromProviders(
      
      createCodecProviderIgnoreNone[MyModel]
    ),
    DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY
  )
}
```

smth went wrong and I get exception while trying to read document from DB

```
Error in block: readString can only be called when CurrentBSONType is STRING, not when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT., null, Stacktrace:
 org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readString can only be called when CurrentBSONType is STRING, not when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT.
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:689)
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:721)
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readString(AbstractBsonReader.java:456)
    at org.bson.codecs.StringCodec.decode(StringCodec.java:80)
    at org.bson.codecs.StringCodec.decode(StringCodec.java:31)
    at org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.macrocodecs.MacroCodec.readDocument(MacroCodec.scala:232)
    at org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.macrocodecs.MacroCodec.readDocument$(MacroCodec.scala:225)
    at com.awesomecompany.MongoCodecs$$anon$30$MyModelMacroCodec$1.readDocument(MongoCodecs.scala:55)
```

It gives a clue that MyModel has string field, but DB contains DOCUMENT value for that field.
Is there any chance to print that whole broken doc to log and get more sense from this extremely useful and clear exception?

Comment: What is `MyModel`? Try to create reproduction. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) It's hard to debug your code remotely and blindly. Maybe you can make a request to db, look at mongo shell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888126 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63948941 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488508 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54663311 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66415106

Comment: Yeah, I did look at DB and know what's the problem. My goal is have some code on application side. Code would dump "bad" document to log so I don't have to review DB manually and search for bad doc. The issue was that case class MyModel has field:String, but mongodb had `{"some":"object"}` for that field